# p:confirm: message attribute not recieve bean value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My datatable has a 'Delete' button on each data field.
On clicking, a confirm dialog will be shown with message as `Are you sure you want to delete 'dataId'?` 
I tried to use `p:confirm` and customize it's message attribute.
Problem is that I can't call 'dataId' from data field. 
You can take a look at my code here:

```
<p:dataTable id="trip-dtbl" rows="10" 
    value="#{tripBean.tripsList}" var="trip">
    <p:column headerText="ID">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{trip.id}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Action" >
        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" update="trip-dtbl"
            action="#{tripsBean.removeTrip(trips)}">
            <p:confirm header="Confirm Delete"
                message="Are you sure you want to delete #{trip.id}?" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The 'trip.id' displayed in the table column but not in confirmDialog.
Why that happen?

Comment: Which primefaces jar version are you using? in primefaces 5.1, there is p:confirmDailog that you could use.

Comment: It exist already since 3.5.

Comment: ok..i was not able to find the same in primefaces showcase..thats why i asked?

Comment: Still looking for answer. I'm manually creating confirmDialog for each custom confirm like this.                 globalConfirm would save me alot.

Comment: Maybe no one helped because there is **no** dataId in your code